# Unable to use driver object of webdriver class inside class and outside method but able to access it inside a method of same classCan anyone explain?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Inside class and outside method I am unable to access Webdriver class methods but inside a method of the same class, I can access methods. I am confused why It is happening.

[Please click on the image to know clearly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQmGD.png)

```
package seleniumV1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Test {


    public WebDriver driver;

    driver.  // showing error here and I am unable to see the recommended methods of webdriver class

    public void method()
    {   driver.close();
        driver.getTitle();   
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with WebDriver. This is all about Java basics. Your code is invalid syntax.

The short answer is: In your example you can access the `driver` object from within `method()` only.

The long answer is: read about visibility of variables in Java. This chapter of "Learning Java" should be [a good start](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java-4th/9781449372477/ch06s04.html).